# Connected space or not

Tags: general-topology

If   I  remove from  $\mathbb{C}^3$   the  plane  generated   by (1,1,0) and (0,0,1)  it  remains connected (simply   connected)?  I  seen   that  for $\mathbb{R}^3$ it  is  not   true.

Comment: Since $\mathbb C^3$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^6$, while the plane is $4$-dimensional, the answer is yes, because you have plenty of space to move around in

Comment: @5xum So  if  I   remove  and  the  planes generated  by {(1,0,1), (0,1,0)}  and {(0,1,1), (1,0,0)} it  remains  simply  connected?